# new windows 8.1 alongside with linux

Tags: linux, partitioning, windows-8.1, gpt

I have pretty serious problem while installing any linux alongside windows 8.1.

While trying to install, linux showing that my disk is empty, despite that i just installed windows a moment ago. Same problem occurs while installing windows on disk where linux is preintalled.

I cant install one system alongside another without recreating GPT partition table. Also while booting Hiren's livecd and checking for GPT, most softs tells me that gpt is damaged or unreadable (while windows is installed).

Answer (score 0):

When a Linux partitioning tool claims that the disk is empty when in fact it has partitions is a damaged partition table. This condition can *sometimes* be fixed by my [FixParts program,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts) which is part of the `gdisk` or `gptfdisk` package in most Linux distributions; but sometimes more expert repairs are necessary. If you've just (re-)installed Windows 8.1 in BIOS mode, it's like that you've got leftover GPT data, which FixParts should detect and correct.

Another possible cause of this problem is leftover software RAID data. You may need to futz with RAID settings in your firmware and completely wipe the first *and last* few sectors of the disk with `dd`, as in:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1024
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 seek={disk size in sectors minus ~1024)
```

Comment: its definitively not RAID problem. Disk was never in software or hardware raid ( its locked inside notebook ) and before installing i had an hint about zeroing it completely. I will try to repair disk using gdisk but what about installing windows on linux containing disc? Windows could not find any partition on disk, despite its GPT looks integral.